# squid as reverse proxy (newbie)

Tags: linux, squid, reverse-proxy

I would like to setup a reverse proxy in front of my virtual machines. All DNS records would point to the public IP where squid3 lives and squid would redirect the traffic according to the squid.conf.
 According to http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/MultipleWebservers seemed easy...

However, I am stuck on browser message "The connection was reset" in FF and ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome.

I added these lines on the beginning on my squid.conf:

```
http_port 80
http_access allow all
cache_peer 192.168.0.50 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=server_1
cache_peer_domain server_1 subdomain1.domain.tld
cache_peer 192.168.0.56 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=server_2
cache_peer_domain server_2  subdomain2.domain.tld  domain2.tld
cache deny all
acl all src all
```

The proxy machine has access to the other machines (verified with links)
I don't see anything in squid logs that could help.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

The squid was not running.... It is a fresh ubuntu server 12.04 install with a official squid3 package, but the upstart script is somehow not starting the squid3.

If I type `sudo squid3` manually, eveyrthing works as expected.